# Displaying contents of xls wrongly

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have written a program: 12 Numbers could be chosen from 1 to 49 and the resulting combination numbers automatically are displayed in the spreadsheet, therefore there will be 6 numbers in each column.

Below is my code.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Lotto {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         int lotto[ ] = new int [12];
            boolean drawn;
            for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
                    do {
                            drawn = false;
                            lotto[i] = (int)(49*Math.random())+ 1;
                            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
                                    if (lotto[i] == lotto[j])
                                            drawn = true;
                    } while (drawn);
            }

            for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
                System.out.println(lotto[i]);
            }
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/workbook.xlsx");
            CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
            int i=0;
            while(i<lotto.length/6){
                 XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for(int k=0;k<6;k++){
                for(int j=0;j<lotto.length;j++){

            row.createCell(k).setCellValue(lotto[j]);
                }
            }
            i++;
    }
           // FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

    }

}
```

For example the random numbers generated by the above program is below.

```
30 44 39 7 6 33 19 28 31 21 49 22
```

But in xls file it is inserting as

```
30 30 30 30 30 30
44 44 44 44 44 44
```

I need output as

```
30 44 39 7 6 33
19 28 31 21 49 22
```

Comment: I have decided not to look at non-formated code anymore. And I think I am not the only one. If you could format your code before posting it here, that would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be a logic problem. Try this:

```
XSSFRow row = null;
int rowCounter = 0;
int cellCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++) {
   if ((i % 6) == 0) {
      cellCounter = 0;
      row = (XSSFRow) sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
      rowCounter++;
   }
   row.createCell(cellCounter).setCellValue(lotto[i]);
   cellCounter++;
}
```

Comment: -1 Are you sure it will help. i can see IndexBoundOutOFException due to lotto[i*6+j]

Comment: give me couple of hours please, i will let you know

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement fixed number of rows and columns , for example there will be 12 columns and 41 rows. But data have to be inserted into 6 columns and two rows. Also how to get formula of the cell

Comment: I quite not understand the question. Perhaps you can ask a new question with all the details and I will try to do my best.

Comment: did you checked the question, now you are able to get the question?